Learning Sitecore, how to structure Treelist data templates in Sitecore?
If I am creating a treelist, where each individual item is a base link template containing text and a general link, having below structure
Home
├── About Us
│   ├── Our Team
│   └── Our History
├── Services
│   ├── Consulting
│   ├── Development
│   │   ├── Web Development
│   │   └── Mobile Development
│   └── Design
├── Products
│   ├── Electronics
│   │   ├── Mobile Phones
│   │   └── Laptops
│   └──


The item elements (About Us, Services, Products..) in tree structures should be a folder or the same data template? and where should the sub-item data template go?
Like this
Home
├── About Us (Folder named About us)
│   ├── Our Team (Data Template of our Team)
│   └── Our History (Data Template of our History)
├── Services (Folder named Services)
│   ├── Consulting (Data Template of Consulting)
│   ├── Development (Data Template or Folder?)
│   │   ├── Web Development
│   │   └── Mobile Development
│   └── Design
├── Products (Folder named Products)
│   ├── Electronics
│   │   ├── Mobile Phones
│   │   └── Laptops
│   └──


or this
Home
├── About Us (Data tempalte of About us?)
│   ├── Our Team (Data Template of our Team)
│   └── Our History (Data Template of our History)
├── Services (Data Template of Services)
│   ├── Consulting (Data Template of Consulting)
│   ├── Development (Data Template of Folder?)
│   │   ├── Web Development
│   │   └── Mobile Development
│   └── Design
├── Products (Data Template of Products)
│   ├── Electronics
│   │   ├── Mobile Phones
│   │   └── Laptops
│   └──


Also how do I access items/subitems in my code?

@Yash,Are you trying to create a content tree structure in Sitecore with the above structure? In that case, you need to create a template type with insert options and then create the content tree structure accordingly.
But if you are trying to create a structure for datasource selection by the content author from the tree list field, then just point to the root of the datasource itempath or id in the treelist source field.
Refer to the below question I have provided the answer.
How can one implement Treelist in Sitecore?
Sample code snippet in view:
@using Sitecore.Data.Items
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation

@{
    Item[] defaultData = null;
    var dataSourceId = RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.DataSource;
    var dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dataSourceId);

    Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField MyDefault = dataSource.Fields["MyTreeListField"];
    if (MyDefault != null && MyDefault.TargetIDs != null)
    {
        defaultData = MyDefault.GetItems();
        //To loop its children
        foreach (Item item in defaultData)
        {
            //we can filter based on template name or id here as well if we want

            if (item.TemplateID.Equals( Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse("{guid-value}")))
            {
                string name = item.Name;
                string title = item.Fields["title"].Value;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }

}

Note:
We can multiple value in the treelist field by the content author when you specifying the AllowMultipleSelection = true
Some sample query for source in the Treelist field data template, we can pass id or name of the template that needs to be included or excluded in the selection, or make visible etc.
DataSource=/sitecore/content/SiteA&ExcludeItemsForDisplay={E18F4BC6-46A2-4842-898B-B6613733F06F},{75CC5CE4-8979-4008-9D3C-806477D57619},{1CE3B36C-9B0C-4EB5-A996-BFCB4EAA5287},{B4A0FB13-9758-427C-A7EB-1A406C045192}&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection={239F9CF4-E5A0-44E0-B342-0F32CD4C6D8B},{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}

this Query with SXA Site token, which will be useful in multisite scenario to get data from right site.
DataSource=query:$site/Data/Links

Check the following document https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/sitecore-experience-manager/controlling-the-list-of-items-in-a-selection-field.html#treelist-parameters
if needed more help let me know. I hope it will help :)

thanks again. So which of the above content tree structures will work the one with the data templates? Data Template one or the folder one?

@YashGupta if you planning get the content from your frontend based on template id, or also restricting the treelist to only provide content from certain template then you need to create different data template, but if you just want to show all the content without any restriction for selection then I don't think you need  to create different datatemplate if it is just used as a datasource but not the page template.

@YashGupta
For example, I want  to create the navigation menu like the above structure you have created above, I will create one data template with 2 fields (Navigation title and navigation link) and then create the datasource item based on this template like the below. Here the below structure created from the same template explained above.
Data
    ----HeaderNavigation
______________Nav1
------------------Child1
------------------Child2
______________Nav2
------------------Child1
------------------Child2


Thank you for helping me with my doubt. I finally understand it now! I really appreciate the time and effort for the detailed answers.
